# Android: LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher doConnected exception

Tags: android, exception

Have any one run in to this exception? I got no idea what it is. Getting it on activity resume after clicked home button and return to app.

```
05-31 09:17:09.224: E/AndroidRuntime(18772): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-31 09:17:09.224: E/AndroidRuntime(18772): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-31 09:17:09.224: E/AndroidRuntime(18772):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1125)
05-31 09:17:09.224: E/AndroidRuntime(18772):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1142)
05-31 09:17:09.224: E/AndroidRuntime(18772):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-31 09:17:09.224: E/AndroidRuntime(18772):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-31 09:17:09.224: E/AndroidRuntime(18772):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
05-31 09:17:09.224: E/AndroidRuntime(18772):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
05-31 09:17:09.224: E/AndroidRuntime(18772):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 09:17:09.224: E/AndroidRuntime(18772):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-31 09:17:09.224: E/AndroidRuntime(18772):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-31 09:17:09.224: E/AndroidRuntime(18772):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-31 09:17:09.224: E/AndroidRuntime(18772):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem when my service connection was null:

`bindService(new Intent(this, LocationService.class), lsconn, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);`

i.e. the `lsconn` variable was null (I'd forgotten to initialise it).

HTH